# VPS on clustered Pi

Tags: raspbian, networking, emulation, cluster

Can I setup VPS on a clustered RPi?

I think Raspbian takes only about a 100mb of RAM, so there's plenty of space left to 'virtual'ize another set of simple OS, but I'm not sure how.

Any suggestions for setting up?

Comment: Well is is possible because I saw sites that offer you run software on clustered Pi's. But they did not disclose how they did it. Maybe some kind of custom middle ware, of possibly the new BSD Beehive stuff?